# Adding nodes to objects in Inkscape by Python script

Tags: python, inkscape

This question is for someone with experience of Python coding of Inkscape extensions. Others need not waste their time, unless they really like a challenge!

I've written a Python extension that calculates the intersections between the line segments of different lines/polyline objects. I want to append new nodes to both objects at these intersection points (obviously in the correct node path order) but I have no idea how to approach this. The code in other extension scripts (e.g. "Modify Path\Add Nodes...") includes the use of `node.set()`, but I can't come close to figuring out how this is supposed to work.  The script is available [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46043231/apps/AddIntersectNodes.zip) if needed, but I don't see how that can help as there is no problem with it - it just produces intersection coordinates.

Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Hey Geo -- I'm trying to do the same thing you were, with your AddIntersectNodes code.  The dropbox link is dead...could you provide the python code again?  Many thanks!  T.

Comment: I'll have a look in my archives

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a long time ago, but I've just written a little extension that allows you to type in a couple lines of python, and iterate it over selected objects. 
It comes with code examples and pointers to documentation (cos the inkscape python modules aren't the best documented!).

Downside is, it crashes inkscape badly if your script returns malformed document. But it's good for quick hacks and testing code fragments.

- http://smanohar.com/inkscape.php

Maybe this will be useful to other people too.